# using a javascript variable in jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf

I want to show/hide a table on clicking for which I have used a javascript function as:

```
function changeTableStyle(){
    if(document.getElementById('incompleteMigratedTable').style.display=='none')
    {
        document.getElementById('incompleteMigratedTable').style.display = '';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('incompleteMigratedTable').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

where style none is by default given when page loads. In other file, which is included in this one I have created the button as

```
<h:CommandLink  id="show_details"
                onclick="changeTableStyle()"
                value="View"
                style="margin-left: 2px;font-weight:bold;color:blue;" >
    <f:ajax execute="@this"
            immediate="true"
            render="incompleteMigratedTable"
            event="click" ajaxSingle="true"
            />
</h:CommandLink>
```

this functionality works perfectly but the requirement is when it shows the table, text of button should change to 'Hide' and vice-versa.
Can we create a variable in javascript function and use it in h:commandLink somehow to achieve this?

Comment: So you want on a button click to change the visibility of a table and change the title of the button from show to hide or the other way around?

Comment: yes, the visibility function is working, I am not able to change the text of the button on clicking. These two snippets are in different xhtml files, ajax code is included in javascipt code file and since its a dynamic code, I am not able to find the id of commandLink tag.

Comment: BTW be careful with `style.display = ''` some browsers don't like it! They want a value and throw error for an empty value. Try `style.display = 'initial'` instead

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend changing your javascript slightly so that it can be used for more than one object (and changing your xhtml to work with it).

**XHTML:**

```
<h:CommandLink id="show_details"
               onclick="toggleVisibility(this,document.getElementById('incompleteMigratedTable'))"
               value="View"
               style=margin-left:2px;font-weight:bold;color:blue;">
  <f:ajax execute="@this"
          immediate="true"
          render="incompleteMigratedTable"
          event="click" ajaxSingle="true"/>
</h:CommandLink>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function toggleVisibility(link,table) {
  if (table.style.display === 'none') {
    table.style.display = '';
    link.innerHTML = 'Hide';
  } else {
    table.style.display = 'none';
    link.innerHTML = 'Show';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its working perfectly. I was not aware of innerHTML feature as I am novice in Javascript. Will keep in mind.

Comment: @user3848979 If that works, you should mark it as the answer so that the question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
<h:CommandLink  id="show_details"
                onclick="changeTableStyle(this)"
                value="View"
                style="margin-left: 2px;font-weight:bold;color:blue;" >
    <f:ajax execute="@this"
            immediate="true"
            render="incompleteMigratedTable"
            event="click" ajaxSingle="true"
            />
</h:CommandLink>
```

Then in the changeTableStyle function you will have the element directly.

```
function changeTableStyle(button_element){
    if(document.getElementById('incompleteMigratedTable').style.display=='none')
    {
        // set button_element title to hide
        document.getElementById('incompleteMigratedTable').style.display = '';
    }
    else
    {
        // set button_element title to show
        document.getElementById('incompleteMigratedTable').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Append another JS-function in the `onclick` attribute, pass the button as argument and change the text there:

```
onclick="changeTableStyle();changeButtonText(this);"
```

And the JS-function:

```
function changeButtonText(btn) {
    btn.value = btn.value === 'View' ? 'Hide' : 'View';
}
```

You can also do both in `changeTableStyle`, depends on your structure and if you need to hide the table without changing the buttons text.

---

If you provide more details about your use case I could maybe give a more proper answer on this. But you definitely can not put a JS-variable as attribute in JSF.